# Java Swing: getAncestorOfClass() not working as expected

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, jtoolbar

Our Java product has a main `JToolBar` where, from a certain point onwards, a couple of background Threads can add new JButtons, starting from the extreme right, as alarms, according to some met conditions during their routines.
So, our main frame has a private attribute like this:

```
private final Component featuresHorizontalGlue = Box.createHorizontalGlue();
```

and when alarm Threads refresh, they firstly call

```
private synchronized void manageHorizontalGlue(boolean toBeAdded) {
    if (toBeAdded) {
        if (SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(toolbar.getClass(), featuresHorizontalGlue) == null) {
            logger.debug("Adding Horizontal Glue to main ToolBar");
            toolbar.toolbar.add(featuresHorizontalGlue);
        }
    }
}
```

as the `HorizontalGlue` component should be unique, so that each following added alarm button will be right aligned. 
A similar method is called when alarm buttons are added for the first time in the toolbar, then they are simply refreshed in their icons.
Anyway, an ex colleague of mine implemented some methods where, if some other conditions are met, main toolbar is completely disposed and recreated.
And so, I expected that my alarm methods worked fine but they do not because even if a new constructor is called on `toolbar`, then `getAncestorOfClass()` returns not null and so horizontal glue and alarm buttons are not re-added and showed anymore.
Why this?
If I inspect with debug on Eclipse the `Components[]` array inside toolbar, I cannot see anymore those buttons and `HorizontalGlue` component. So, why does that method not return null?

Comment: We cannot answer your question because we don't see your code. Please provide a short runnable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), so we can also reproduce your problem and debug it to find a solution.

Comment: Sorry, but I just wanted to know if possible how that  ` getAncestorOfClass()` works of if I misunderstood anything. I am afraid it is no simple to give a short runnable example as the package into which I am currently working is very big and there are a lot of classes and method which cause that...also the toolbar is very complex. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you misunderstood the purpose of this method, which is strange, as its name “`getAncestorOfClass`” clearly indicates that it will return an ancestor having a matching class, not necessarily the instance, you have in mind. If that’s not enough, you are passing `toolbar.getClass()` to it, not the `toolbar` instance. So it even couldn’t check whether it is the same instance; it will simply return any ancestor `JToolBar` instance, if there is one, e.g. the old toolbar.

In the end, if you want to know whether `toolbar` is an ancestor of `featuresHorizontalGlue`, you can test it straight-forwardly using `toolBar.isAncestorOf(featuresHorizontalGlue)`. No need to look into any extra utility class.

Besides that, when I read “*a couple of background Threads can add new JButtons*”, I hope, you have read and understood [Swing’s Threading Policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading)…

Comment: Thank you, it was very very kind of yours. As I feared, I had completely misunderstood that method. I admit I am not good neither at using these utilities classes or at using Swing... anyway, I appreciated also your hint about Swing threading policy. In fact, each time there's need to add or remove the button, or change its icon, I use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. Thank you very much.